# How index cifs server with solr

Tags: solr, cifs

is it possible to index some document on cifs server with solr ?

Thanks

Comment: CIFS as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365233.aspx ? What concretely do you need to do with it? Use Data import handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIFS is an network protocol. Solr does not "talk" CIFS. But if your Server is able to mound the CIFS Volume, you can index those documents.
If the CIFS share is shared by an windows or linux Server, it's also possible to run Solr on the fileserver, because Solr/Lucene is written in Java and will work on windows an linux as well.

For importing the document use the data import handler (DIH), as Mauricio Scheffer wrote.
The DIH is able to crawl an directory recursive in order to index the data he find.

Comment: thank you. So it's impossible to do this dynamically and i have to mount the server file on server running solr.